# How to link community with wiki pages programatically using IBM SBT

Tags: ibm-sbt

Can anyone please tell me how to link the community while creating wiki pages programmatically using javascript. While working with a wiki on the playground, wiki pages are getting created but it is not under any community. Community id is null.

Where to configure the community while creating a wiki page programmatically using javascript.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the community id for the wiki like below

```
var wiki = wikiService.newWiki(); 
wiki.setTitle(title);
wiki.setCommunityUuid(communityId);
wikiService.createWiki(wiki);
```

Comment: rajmeet still it is not working.always i get the response without community id in it.community uuid is null.May be thats why i can see the wikis created independently.